# Estoy intentando coger todos los valores de un textView que pertenece a un item de un recycler despues de darle a un boton.¿Es posible?

Tags: android-studio

#No soy capaz de solucionar una nullPointerException que me da al intentar recoger los valores que hay en un textView que pertener a un item del recyclerView. Creo que se debe a que como el recyclerView tiene scroll no encuentra el textView que quiero ya que si pruebo con solo 3 items en el recycler#

```
comprar.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "lalalalalalala", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ArrayList<Integer> cantidades = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < productosAdapter.getItemCount(); i++){
                View itemView = recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                TextView tvCant = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cantidad);
                int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(tvCant.getText().toString());
                cantidades.add(cantidad);

            }
            Log.d("cantidades", "Cantidades: " + cantidades.toString());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Para sacar la posicion del textview que estas seleccionando debes utilizar:

```
int pos=rv.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
```

Donde rv es tu reciclerView y este int te servirá para obtener los datos desde la lista que enviaste a tu adaptador algo así:

```
String dato=Lista.get(pos);
```